# Python: How Close (or exit) Python Process After QMainWindow Dialog is closed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qmainwindow

There are two .py files placed in a same folder:

```
dialog_01.py and dialog_02.py
```

Both files are copy of each other. Both build a simple QMainWindow dialog window with two buttons: 'Ok' and 'Cancel'.

Clicking 'Ok' button closes a currently opened dialog window and opens another. So if Dialog_01's Ok button is clicked the dialog_01 is closed and dialog_02 is opened. If Dialog_02's Ok button is clicked then dialog_02 is closed and dialog_01 is opened and so on.

## EDITED QUESTION:

Closing the dialog box leaves Python process still running at the background (it can be seen in OSX Activity Monitor or Windows Task Manager).

**How to make sure the Python process is terminated after the dialog window is closed?**

## dialog_01.py

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui    
if 'app' not in globals().keys(): app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class Dialog_01(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow,self).__init__()

        myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()       

        Cancel_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        Cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.Cancel)      
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(Cancel_button) 


        Button_01 = QtGui.QPushButton("Press to close this dialog and open Dialog 02")
        Button_01.clicked.connect(self.callAnotherQMainWindow)
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(Button_01)        

        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle('Dialog 01')

    def callAnotherQMainWindow(self):
        from dialog_02 import Dialog_02
        self.close()
        self.dialog_02 = Dialog_02()
        self.dialog_02.show()
        self.dialog_02.raise_()

    def Cancel(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self):
        self.deleteLater()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    dialog_1 = Dialog_01()
    dialog_1.show()
    dialog_1.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## dialog_02.py

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui    
if 'app' not in globals().keys(): app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class Dialog_02(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow,self).__init__()

        myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        Cancel_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        Cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.Cancel)      
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(Cancel_button) 


        Button_02 = QtGui.QPushButton("Press to close this dialog 02 and re-open Dialog 01")
        Button_02.clicked.connect(self.callAnotherQMainWindow)
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(Button_02)

        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle('Dialog 02')

    def callAnotherQMainWindow(self):
        from dialog_01 import Dialog_01
        self.close()
        self.dialog_01 = Dialog_01()
        self.dialog_01.show()
        self.dialog_01.raise_()

    def Cancel(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self):
        self.deleteLater()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dialog_2 = Dialog_02()
    dialog_2.show()
    dialog_2.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the closeEvent() function of your QtGui.QMainWindow classes like below:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    self.deleteLater()
```

This seemed to work:

Removing this:

```
if 'app' not in globals().keys(): app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

and this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dialog_2 = Dialog_02()
    dialog_2.show()
    dialog_2.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

...from dialog2 file did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But now I'm getting this:   TypeError: closeEvent() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: I've just edited a code posted in original question with the lines you suggested in place. Please take a look... since I am still getting the same error on arguments:  TypeError: closeEvent() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Okay was hoping that was it, I'm testing the code out now to see if I can find the problem, maybe something simple I'm missing.

Comment: I think there must be an incoming argument declared such as :      def closeEvent(self, event): self.deleteLater()  .... but that still leaves the Python process running...

Comment: Ha, oddly enough I didn't think that was the problem since you technically don't need the "event" but ya that got rid of the error message. Hm, one reason I could see of it still being open is that you're only closing one of the dialogs properly from the self.deleteLater() and the other one is not properly closing.

Comment: Got it, check the edit. Don't need that extra stuff since you're (I think) just starting you're python program from dialog1.

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm now. The bottom line: do not experiment too much with app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example.

## dialog_01.py

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui  

class Dialog_01(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow,self).__init__()

        myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()       

        Cancel_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        Cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.Cancel)      
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(Cancel_button) 


        Button_01 = QtGui.QPushButton("Press to close this dialog and open Dialog 02")
        Button_01.clicked.connect(self.callAnotherQMainWindow)
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(Button_01)        

        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle('Dialog 01')

    def callAnotherQMainWindow(self):
        from dialog_02 import Dialog_02
        self.close()
        self.dialog_02 = Dialog_02()
        self.dialog_02.show()
        self.dialog_02.raise_()

    def Cancel(self):
        self.close()

    # def closeEvent(self, event):
    #     self.deleteLater()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog_1 = Dialog_01()
    dialog_1.show()
    dialog_1.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## dialog_02.py

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui    

class Dialog_02(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow,self).__init__()

        myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        Cancel_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        Cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.Cancel)      
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(Cancel_button) 


        Button_02 = QtGui.QPushButton("Press to close this dialog 02 and re-open Dialog 01")
        Button_02.clicked.connect(self.callAnotherQMainWindow)
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(Button_02)

        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle('Dialog 02')

    def callAnotherQMainWindow(self):
        from dialog_01 import Dialog_01
        self.close()
        self.dialog_01 = Dialog_01()
        self.dialog_01.show()
        self.dialog_01.raise_()

    def Cancel(self):
        self.close()

    # def closeEvent(self, event):
    #     self.deleteLater()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog_2 = Dialog_02()
    dialog_2.show()
    dialog_2.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```